# WPF ListBox items alignment and in order?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Is it possible to fill a listBox with items which have predefined index?
Such as if I have collection of items with index values:

- item1, index 1
- item2, index 2
- item3, index 4

**ListBox:**

- item1
- item2
- *empty space*
- item3

the list can contain any number of combination of empty or filled positions.

Which methods would be the most direct way of achieving the desired result with MVVM structure in a WPF environment?

Comment: Create model class with two property `item` and `index` but add item sequentially in `ListBox`

Comment: Bind the ListBox's `ItemsSource` to a collection with `null` items for the empty spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this MVVMfully, your list box items will be an `ObservableCollection` of instances of some class of your own, which represents whatever you're putting in the listbox (users, used cars, whatever). That collection is a property on your viewmodel.

At the `ListBox` end of things, you'll have to represent empty slots with spacer items -- `null` should do fine. You'd then do something in the view with the ListBox's `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle` to display the "empty" items correctly and prevent them from being selected by the user. You might have to handle the `SelectionChanged` event to make that happen; if you want to reuse this stuff in a generalized way, you could handle `SelectionChanged` via an attached property that your style would apply.

Option 1, not quite the purest MVVM but a whole lot less work than Doing It Right, is very simple: When you populate your `ObservableCollection`, sort the items and insert nulls for spacer items. Done.

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding WeirdGappyCollectionWithNulls}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GappyItemTemplate}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GappyItemContainerStyle}"
    />
```

...where `GappyItemTemplate` and `GappyItemContainerStyle` are defined in a `ResourceDictionary` above.

Option 2, if you want to go Full MVVMtard and build for the ages:

For sorting, I'd ordinarily use a sorted [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you're binding that to ItemsSource

```
<ListBox 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GappyItemTemplate}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GappyItemContainerStyle}"
    >
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <local:GappyCollectionViewSource
            Source="{Binding GappyCollection}"
            ...etc. etc.
            />
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

I wouldn't want the viewmodel to have any clue about ListBoxes, or even about empty items.

I would give the viewmodel a gappy collection of "non empty" items, and write a `CollectionViewSource` subclass that will sort by whatever property you like, and additionally project that collection to another, readonly collection which includes null "spacer" items, which it exposes in its [`View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms594734(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Sort of an anti-filter. It could use the `SortDescriptions` to define what the gaps are, at least if you're sorting by integers. Or you could do that part semi-quick and dirty by giving it a keyselector lambda or an event analogous to the existing [Filter event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms521600(v=vs.110).aspx).

`CollectionViewSource.View` isn't a virtual property, but it is a `DependencyProperty`. There should be some way to slip in a ringer there. If that gives you any trouble, start over with [`CollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: how about using an [attached behaviour approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF)? Such as the each item on the listBox contains the index.

Comment: or as a blend behaviour?

Comment: @ajr Do you mean an attached property applied to `ListBox` that would fill in the dummy items when the collection changes, and put an attached index property on the `ListBoxItem` instances? Aside from all the work, I expect it would run afoul of virtualization (how do you sort a collection of 200 ListBoxItems when only 20 of them actually exist?). I don't know how you would sort ListBoxItems themselves anyway. It's probably doable, but that sort of thing has never in my experience been the path of least resistance with WPF.

Comment: True, performance is suffering with that kind of approach. Thank you for the insight! I decided to go with the **option 1**, by inserting values into the correct places when first time creating the collection.